# Is onDraw() called before or after onActivityCreated()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-canvas, android-view, ondraw

I am inflating a layout in the `onCreateView()` of my Fragment. This layout contains a custom view. Now the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) of `onActivityCreated()` says that it's "*Called when the fragment's activity has been created and this fragment's view hierarchy instantiated*". This means that the layout is inflated and the views in the layout are created before `onActivityCreated()`.

So does this mean the view's `onLayout()`, `onSizeChanged()` and `onDraw()` methods are called before `onActivityCreated()`?

Comment: Why not simply log the method calls? :)

Comment: that's what i finally did to understand how a view's lifecycle works along with the fragment's lifecycle. I just put the logs for reference, mostly for my  own reference :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NO**

`onActivityCreated()` is called first. `onSizeChanged()`, `onLayout()` and `onDraw()` are called later. What the documentation meant by "*view hierarchy instantiated*" is that the views are created (their respective constructors are called) and you could use a `findViewById()` to get the reference to the views. And that is all.

What is the significance of this? Well, this means that you cannot get the `width` or `height` of the view in `onActivityCreated()`. It would simply return 0.

Below is the order in which the methods are called:

> 1 -> `Fragment` - `onCreateView()`
>   2 -> `View`        - `CustomView()` //Constructor
>   3 -> `Fragment` - `onViewCreated()`
>   4 -> `Fragment` - `onActivityCreated()`
>   5 -> `Fragment` - `onResume()`
>   6 -> `View`        - `onMeasure()`
>   7 -> `View`        - `onSizeChanged()`
>   8 -> `View`        - `onLayout()`
>   9 -> `View`        - `onDraw()`